# 2 cars moving from the same point, related rates.

Tags: calculus

2 cars start from the same point. Car A moves south at 60 $\frac{mi}{h}$ and car B travels west at 25 $\frac{mi}{h}$. At what rate is the distance between the cars increasing after 2 hours?

Using the Pythagorean theorem I got $2x \frac{dx}{dt}+2y \frac{dy}{dt}=2z \frac{dz}{dt}$

Plugging in the values after 2 hours I got

$$2(120)(60)+2(50)(25)=2z \frac{dz}{dt}$$

I am not sure where to go from because I can't find the value of z.

Comment: In fact, because both cars move at constant speed along straight lines, the rate of increase of the distance between them is constant. That is, the rate after two hours is the same as the rate after one hour or after one microsecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the rate of change of the distance between the two cars is $\dfrac{dz}{dt}$

We know that $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=60,\ \ \dfrac{dy}{dt}=25$$

By using Pythagorean theorem we have

$x^2+y^2=z^2$

Now implicitly differentiate with respect to $t$ to get

$$2x\dfrac{dx}{dt}+2y\dfrac{dy}{dt}=2z\ \dfrac{dz}{dt}$$

Now plug in the numbers. After $2$ hours

$$x=60(2)=120$$
and $$y=25(2)=50$$

$$z^2=(120)^2+(50)^2$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yup, I solve for z then plug it back into the differentiated formula. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are using two different variables for the distance between the cars.  To be consistent, you should change $\frac{ds}{dt}$ to $\frac{dz}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

The distance between the two cars is given by

$$
\delta(t) = || \vec v_1 t - \vec v_2 t|| = ||\vec v_1 - \vec v_2|| t
$$

so the rate for $\delta(t)$ is $\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t) = ||\vec v_1 - \vec v_2||$

NOTE

Given $\vec v = (v_x, v_y)$ then $||\vec v|| = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$